# How to go from solana_transaction_status::UiCompiledInstruction accounts: Vec<u8> to Vec<String>?

Tags: transactions, transaction-instructions, instruction

My initial input is a `EncodedConfirmedTransactionWithStatusMeta` (see [struct doc](https://docs.rs/solana-transaction-status/latest/solana_transaction_status/struct.EncodedConfirmedTransactionWithStatusMeta.html)). Then I am parsing instructions of type `UiCompiledInstruction` (see [struct doc](https://docs.rs/solana-transaction-status/latest/solana_transaction_status/struct.UiCompiledInstruction.html)).

The struct has a field `accounts` of type `accounts: Vec<u8>`.

In order to map these indexes to a public key I have created a vec after retrieving the transaction:

```
let mut instructions = vec![];

// Create indexed key vec
let outer_keys: Vec<String> = match &tx_encoded.transaction.transaction {
    solana_transaction_status::EncodedTransaction::Json(ui_transaction) => {
        let raw = match &ui_transaction.message {
            solana_transaction_status::UiMessage::Raw(v) => v,
            _ => todo!()
        };
        for raw_i in &raw.instructions {
            instructions.push(UiInstruction::Compiled(raw_i.clone()))
        }
        raw.account_keys.clone()
    }
    _ => todo!(),
};
```

However the instruction's (`UiCompiledInstruction`) `accounts: Vec<u8>` field contains indexes > `outer_keys.len()`. I retrieved the instructions via

```
if let solana_transaction_status::option_serializer::OptionSerializer::Some(v) =
    tx_encoded.transaction.meta.unwrap().inner_instructions
{
    for inner in v {
        instructions.extend(inner.instructions);
    }
}
```

What is the correct way to map `accounts: Vec<u8>` to `accounts: Vec<String>` to get he PK of the account?